# Синтаксическое средство (задание № 25 ЕГЭ)

Tags: синтаксис, егэ

> От телефониста Юрий Андреевич перешёл на поляну к телу убитого молодого
>   белогвардейца. На красивом лице юноши были написаны черты невинности и всё простившего страдания. **«Зачем?» — подумал доктор.**

(По Б. Пастернаку)

Какое синтаксическое средство использовано в выделенном фрагменте?

Comment: Эллипсис? .....

Comment: @slava1947 увы! (Вот вы не можете ответить, а дети!?)

Comment: Увы...  А в задании не приведены четыре варианта ответа, из которых надо было бы выбрать _правильный_?

Comment: @slava1947 конечно приведены — целых девять. Но интерес в том, чтобы понять, можно ли другим путем прийти к тому ответу, который дан в ключах.

Comment: Интересно, а почему изменен текст?  От телефониста Юрий Андреевич перешел на поляну к телу убитого ИМ молодого белогвардейца. На красивом лице юноши были написаны черты невинности и всё простившего страдания. „Зачем Я УБИЛ ЕГО?“ — подумал доктор.

Comment: @Sharon ну, испугались составители жестокости и откровенности признания. Или хотели подогнать текст под свои «проблемы».

Comment: Мне кажется, что это их нисколько не извиняет. Ведь вопрос о средствах выразительности касается именно измененного предложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не риторический вопрос, то просто "вопросительное предложение". В общем-то, это точно не риторический, он же и правда спрашивает себя, зачем убил этого мальчика, его мучит это бессмысленное убийство, он чувствует себя убийцей.

Comment: Не знал, что в списке синтаксических средств есть  "вопросительное предложение". А повествовательное там тоже есть? Где можно такой список увидеть?

Comment: Вопросительное и восклицательное предложение очень часто встречается в последнем задании. Общий список вряд ли существует. Посмотрите на сайте ФИПИ в КИМах. Любое синтаксическое средство может использоваться как фигура речи. Вот здесь именно этот вопрос характеризует отрицательное отношение доктора Живаго к войне, к убийству. Восклицательное предложение тоже не всегда риторическое восклицание, иногда оно может не просто привлекать внимание, а характеризовать человека (чем восторгается).

Answer (score 1):

Из перечисленных [тут](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/sintaksicheskie-sredstva-hudojestvennoy-52826.html) синтаксических средств я бы выбрал инверсию и риторический вопрос. А если можно выбрать только одно, то риторический вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! В ЕГЭшной книжке ответ другой :) Ждем, когда его назовут...

Comment: Можно сделать еще одну попытку?

Comment: Конечно! (Кстати, я не говорил, что не согласен с вашим ответом ;))

Comment: Мне кажется, можно дать несколько верных ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая попытка. Умолчание — оборот речи, заключающийся в том, что автор сознательно не до конца выражает мысль, предоставляя читателю / слушателю самому догадаться о невысказанном.

Comment: Тоже интересный вариант, но вот составители практикума мыслят, видимо, иначе.

Comment: Я могу и дальше предлагать "интересные" варианты, но надо оставить место другим участникам.